# Is there a way to get Netbeans PHP play nicely with CakePHP2 lazy-loading?

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-2.0, isset

In CakePHP 1.3 I usually add model property definitions and PHPDoc to my models and controllers like so:

```
/**
 * @var Vegetable
 */
public $Vegetable;
```

In Netbeans this gives "Intellisense"-style autosuggestion, displays PHPDoc information, and is generally a boon. Unfortunately in CakePHP 2 it seems that this causes the model lazy-loading to fail because the magic methods `__isset()` and `__get()` are never called for properties that already exist.

The lack of autosuggest would be a bitter pill to swallow - has anyone come across this issue, and can you see any workarounds?

Comment: If you're voting to close please share your wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @property annotation (in class decription).

Comment: Thanks @tmysik, wasn't aware of this tag, easiest solution possible. [property documentation here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html)